# Scrolling info box (per article) plugin for Wordpress?

Tags: scroll, wordpress

I have a wordpress blog and what I need is a plugin which adds an info box like http://css-tricks.com/examples/ScrollingSidebar/ whose content can be defined when writing an article. Is there something like that out there or do you have ideas how to accomplish that?

So the box is always there, but the content changes for each article.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for: http://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/

the jquery plugin can be found here: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/stickyfloat